# Dealing with linebreaks in while read line

Tags: bash, awk

Maybe I'm using the wrong tool for the job here...

My data looks like this (this is from a json file which has been converted to a csv):

```
"hostname1",1,""
"hostname2",1,""
"hostname3",0,"yay_some_text
more_text
more_text
"
```

The first column is the hostname, second is the exit code and the third the result. I usually do something like this and make a moderately pretty table:

```
cat tmp.file | ( while read line
do
name=$(echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $1}')
exit_code=$(echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $2}')
output=$(echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $3}')
#I can then do stuff with the output here and ultimately do this:
echo -e "|${name}\t|${exit_code}\t|${output}\t|"
done
)
```

However the third column is causing me no end of problems; I think regardless of what I do, the read line bit will make this impossible. Does anyone have a better method of sorting this? I'd ideally like to keep the linebreaks, but if thats going to be too hard, I'll happily replace them with commas.

Desired output (either is fine):

```
| hostname1 | 1 | |
| hostname2 | 1 | |
| hostname3 | 0 | yay_some_text
 more_text 
more_text |
```

```
| hostname1 | 1 | |
| hostname2 | 1 | |
| hostname3 | 0 | yay_some_text, more_text, more_text |
```

Comment: have you tried `jq`? in your case, it can be used to prepare a `csv` from `json` with a more simpler structure..

Comment: @SamDaniel the csv comes from jq, haha. The output of one of the fields had line breaks in it :/ (presented as \n) which I've reformatted using jq -r...

Comment: @user3229731 you accepted the first answer you got and unfortunately it's completely wrong as it will be extremely slow and fail in new and exciting ways given various input values, contents of the directory you run it from, and environment variable settings. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for **some** of the issues. You might want to ask a new question and this time give it some time to see what answers you get as the first answer you get may not always be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, one way is , you can transform the file to a simpler structure before using

```
  awk '/[^"]$/ { printf("%s", $0); next } 1' tmp.file | ( while read line
  do
    name=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1}')
    exit_code=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $2}')
    output=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $3}')
    #I can then do stuff with the output here and ultimately do this:
    echo -e "|${name}\t|${exit_code}\t|${output}\t|"
  done
  )
```

If all you want to do is to display as a table, you can use `column` utility

```
awk '/[^"]$/ { printf("%s", $0); next } 1' tmp.file | column -t -o "  |  " -s ,
```

If you are so particular about the starting and ending seperator '|', you can simply pipe the output of this command to a `sed`|`awk`.

Comment: That's basically done it, thanks! There's a bit of logic in the table so column isn't a great option. Thanks again :D

Comment: This is one of those cases where someone asks how to load their gun while looking down the  barrel and instead of advising them not to do that, you show them how :-). If it's not too late - don't do that!

Answer (score 4):

Whichever of these you prefer will work robustly* and efficiently using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
/"$/ {
    gsub(/[[:space:]]*"[[:space:]]*/,"",rec)
    gsub(/,/," | ",rec)
    printf "| %s |\n", rec
    rec = ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
| hostname1 | 1 |  |
| hostname2 | 1 |  |
| hostname3 | 0 | yay_some_text
more_text
more_text |
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = rec $0 RS }
/"$/ {
    gsub(/[[:space:]]*"[[:space:]]*/,"",rec)
    gsub(/,/," | ",rec)
    gsub(RS,", ",rec)
    printf "| %s |\n", rec
    rec = ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
| hostname1 | 1 |  |
| hostname2 | 1 |  |
| hostname3 | 0 | yay_some_text, more_text, more_text |
```

*robustly assuming your quoted strings never contain commas or escaped double quotes, i.e. it looks like the example you provided and your existing code relies on.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ gawk -v RS='"\n' -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' -v OFS=' | ' '
           {gsub(/"/,""); $1=$1; print OFS $0 OFS}' file


 | hostname1 | 1 |  |
 | hostname2 | 1 |  |
 | hostname3 | 0 | yay_some_text
more_text
more_text
 |
```